# Django translating choice fields

Tags: python, django, translation

I've got some models like this:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    class Status(IntEnum):
        open = 0
        balance = 2
        closed = 1
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=enum_to_choices(Status), default=0, verbose_name=_("Status"))
```

I'm using a enum to denote my choices and to use them throughout other parts of my application. I'm converting these to tuples to use in choice fields with the following code:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
def enum_to_choices(enum):
    x = tuple([(x.value, _(x.name.replace("_", " "))) for x in enum])
    return x
```

The conversion part of the code works, i can use these fields as choices but the translation doesn't work, it doesn't show up in my translation files.
If i change the parameter to uggettext_lazy with a static string like `"open"` it does show up.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is related to the `makemessages` command, which for some reason struggles with non-static strings.

I couldn't elaborate on the why, but here's how you can solve the problem:

You actually have to **manually create the strings in the translation files**
(django.po):

```
#: .\polls\models.py:enum_to_choices

msgid "open"
msgstr "ouvert"

msgid "closed"
msgstr "fermé"

msgid "balance"
msgstr "solde"
```

Don't forget to `django-admin compilemessages`, and translated strings should appear!
This is not ideal, especially for long enums, but better than nothing.

If someone here knows the inner workings of `makemessages` (and the `xgettext` program it uses) and has an explanation, please let us know ^^

---

## Other solution: use recommended choices structure

Another solution, if you don't absolutely need the choices to be in enums, is using the choices structure [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Payment(models.Model):
    OPEN = 0
    CLOSED = 1
    BALANCE = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN, _('open')),
        (CLOSED, _('closed')),
        (BALANCE, _('balance')),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=OPEN, verbose_name=_("Status"))
```

And then on `django-admin makemessages` the strings will be added to the translation files.

You can easily get the value of a choice, as you would with an enum :

```
from .models import Payment
new_payment = Payment.objects.create(status=Payment.OPEN)
```